# How to solve $y'-2xy=e^{\frac{1}{x}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this ODE :

$$y'-2xy=e^{\frac{1}{x}}$$

So I tried multiplying the equation by the integrating factor : $e^{\int-2xdx}=e^{-x^2}$.

$$\begin{align}\Rightarrow (ye^{-x^2})'&=e^{\frac{1}{x}}\cdot e^{-x^2}\\&=e^{\frac{1-x^3}{x}}\end{align}$$
$$\Rightarrow ye^{-x^2}=\int e^{\frac{1-x^3}{x}}dx$$

However, I couldn't figure out how to perform the integration. So I need some help to continue. Or is there other simpler alternative methods which I have missed out?

Comment: Almost certainly the integral cannot be expressed as elementary functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Barring that this problem is miscopied...)

Your answer "$y = e^{x^2} \int e^{\frac{1-x^3}{x}}\,dx$" is as good as you can do (Wolfram alpha and Maple agree that this function cannot be integrated in terms of elementary functions).

Some DEs texts include variation of parameters and first order linear problems whose answers involve unevaluated integrals.

Alternatively, are you possibly looking for some sort of series type solution?

Comment: Hmm...alright, I guess I'll have to make do with the unevaluated integral.